# Como solucionar o erro "call to undefined method ParameterBag::save() " ?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando salvar os dados do checklist do protocolo, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro no momento de salvar:

> Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::save()
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem a seguir apresenta o model do checklist do protocolo e a segunda imagem é o debug variável request. Este debug apresenta como os dados estão estruturados. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Debug da variável "request", dados oriundos do modal checklist protocolo. Os dados marcados de amarelo são as variáveis do checklist e os dados marcados de vermelho é o id do item do array. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Loop responsável por exibir os dados do checklist do protocolo:**

```
   @foreach($checklistsProtocolos as $checklistProtocolo)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="item" name="item[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
                                    <td>{{$checklistProtocolo->descricao_item}}</td>   
                                    <input type="hidden"          id="item_descricao_id"  name="item_descricao_id[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id}}">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="sim_nao"            name="sim_nao[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]"    {{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="nao_atende"         name="nao_atende[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="date"        id="dt_validade"        name="dt_validade[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="pagina_documento"   name="pagina_documento[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="observacao"         name="observacao[{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}][]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1" style="width: 300px; height: 60px"></td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach
```

**Método de cadastro do checklist do protocolo do controlador:**

```
 public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request)
        {

            dd($request->request);

           //Deletar a tabela de checklist_protocolo
           $checklistsProtocolos = ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id','=', $request->projeto_id)->delete();

           //Recebe os dados do modal Checklist Protocolo
            $checklistProtocolo =  $request->request;

            $checklistProtocolo->save();//está ocorrendo um problema no momento de salvar os dados

        }
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que `$checklistsProtocolo` é um Model?

Answer (score 0):

Para atualizar um modelo usando `save`, primeiro você deve recuperá-lo, definir os atributos que deseja atualizar ou criar e, em seguida, chamar o método save.

No seu caso você não recuperou o modelo, apenas a requisição, que esta salva na variável `$checklistProtocolo` e tentou salva-la.

Tente assim:

```
public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request)
{
    // Deletar a tabela de checklist_protocolo
    $checklistsProtocolos = ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $request->projeto_id)->delete();

    // Recebe os dados do modal Checklist Protocolo
    $dados = $request->all();

    $checklistsProtocolo = new ChecklistProtocolo;

    $checklistProtocolo->save($dados);
}
```

Outra forma seria utilizar o `create`

```
public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request)
{
    // Deletar a tabela de checklist_protocolo
    $checklistsProtocolos = ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $request->projeto_id)->delete();

    $checklistsProtocolo  = ChecklistProtocolo::create($request->all());
}
```

[Referência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Comment: Olá, @Dobrychtop eu fiz a alteração como recomendado, o erro não apareceu. Mas os dados não estão sendo salvos no banco de dados.

Comment: @Ruama, use `dd($request->all());` e verifique o resultado, veja também se os campos estão liberados pra atribuição em massa no seu modelo, dentro do atributo `protected $fillable = ['id','campo','outro_campo'];`

Comment: Oi, @Dobrychtop, eu inserir o seguinte código, mas o erro permanece:  protected  $fillable  = ['projeto_id', 'modelo_id','itens_descricao_id','sim_nao', 'nao_atende','dt_validade','pagina_documento','observacao'];

Comment: Quando eu tentei pela segunda forma utilizando o create, ocorreu o seguinte erro: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `checklist_protocolo` (`projeto_id`, `modelo_id`, `sim_nao`, `nao_atende`, `dt_validade`, `pagina_documento`, `observacao`) values (12, 7, on, on, 2018-11-21, 1, teste))

Comment: @Ruama, você pretende gravar uma linha repetindo `projeto_id`, `modelo_id` para cada um de seus `itens`? Se sim você precisaria usar um` foreach` para cada um deles, formatando manualmente seus campos, como `dados['projeto_id'] = $projeto_id;`, e depois usar o create dentro desse laço pra cada uma de suas linhas.

Comment: Porém essa não seria a abordagem correta, você deveria ter uma tabela com os campos unicos, `projeto_id`, `modelo_id`, e uma tabela que façam grave os itens desse projeto com uma relação N:N no seu modelo, assim o projeto não seria gravado repetidamente, e não importariam quantos itens ou datas ele possua. Mas essa abordagem já foge da questão inicial, e passa até pelas [regras formais](https://www.devmedia.com.br/modelagem-relacional/19614) de normalização de banco de dados relacionais .

Comment: Olá, obrigada pelo retorno. Eu refiz o método e ficou da seguinte forma:

Comment: public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request) {
  $dados = $request->all(); $checklistsProtocolo = new ChecklistProtocolo;
 foreach ($dados  as $dado) { $checklistsProtocolo->projeto_id = $dado['projeto_id'];$checklistsProtocolo->modelo_id = $dado['modelo_id']; $checklistsProtocolo->item = $dado['item']; $checklistsProtocolo->item_descricao_id = $dado['item_descricao_id'];
$checklistsProtocolo->pagina_documento = $dado['pagina_documento'] $checklistsProtocolo->observacao = $dado['observacao']; $checklistsProtocolo->save();}

Comment: Mas, ocorreu o seguinte erro: Illegal string offset 'projeto_id'